# Defining entity with specific column name for a one-to-one relation in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to define some column names using code-first in my entities. I'm using .NET Core 3.1, EF Core 3.1.15 and MySQL server.

I have a relation between entities similar to this situation

I have a `City` that belongs to a `State`. So it is a one-to-one relation from `City` to `State`.

Here's an example

```
public class City 
{
    [Column("IdCity")]
    public short IdCity { get; set; }
    [Column("IdState")] 
    public State State { get; set; }
   
}

public class State
{
    [Column("IdState")]
    public byte IdState { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that if I run a migration and then persist the database change, it generates the following table

Table `City`:

```
IdCity | StateIdState | ....
```

Table `State`:

```
 IdState | ... | ...
```

I need the column `StateIdState` to be defined as `IdState` in the physical database.

I tried using different annotations like FK, column, etc but It did not work, it always generates that name.

Is there a way that I can omit the name of the entity attached to the first part of the column name?

I'm doing this because I already have these two tables created in a server so I need to match their schema in order to interact with them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the previous solution I added the following annotation to keep Entities and Foreign keys in sync.

```
public class City {
   [Column("IdCity")]
   public short IdCity {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("State")]
   public int IdState {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("IdState")]
   public virtual  State State {get;set;}
}

public class State
{
    [Column("IdState")]
    public int IdState { get; set; }
}
```

Now my db schema is correct.

Answer (score 1):

you have a bug, add IdState column and use double quotes

```
public class City {
   [Column("IdCity")]
   public short IdCity {get;set;}
   [Column("IdState")] 
   public byte IdState {get;set;}
   public virtual  State State {get;set;}
     ....
```

but you don't need any column attributes in your case, since EF automaticaly gives the same name. You need it only if you want a column name be different from a property name.

Comment: that's true EF core automatically gives the same name, but the thing is if I define IdState instead of State, it looks kind of weird to interact, it is not an ID, it's an entity with properties.

Comment: @There is no column State, it is not MongoDb, you can  keep only primitive types in each column, you can' t keep the whole class instance.

Comment: I've checked again your solution, my bad, I did not see the virtual variable in the last line.
I'll mark your answer as solution, thanks